# Convert Multi-page pdf document to xml

Tags: python-3.x

is there any method to convert a multi-page pdf document to xml. I have been searching a lot and could not find one for python 3.x?

Comment: what kind of `xml` do you mean, and what is the content of the pdf?

Comment: PDF contains text and tables and I am interested in extracting the tables alone. I tried using tabula, but tabula does not extract with table headers. So looking for further options wherein I would be able to extract table along with the header. Thanks!